# Delegate isn't working like I think that it should be (Lambda Expression is not working)?

Tags: c#

The following code is an example of a simple Lambda expression that works if I create a function1 with the Lambda expression but will not compile if I do not. From what someone told me in another question similar to this (not exact) the compile will generate some of the code for you as is the case in line.

**Question: I am not sure what constitutes the parameter list and the actual code for the Lambda expression?"** (I think that might be what is causing me trouble)

Example:

```
  Console.WriteLine(Test( (input1, input2, input3, input4) => input1 + 
                                                                  " -- " + 
                                                                  input2 + 
                                                                  " -- " +
                                                                  input3 + 
                                                                  " -- " +
                                                                  input4, 
                                                                  "look at this", 
                                                                  "How do you do!");
```

code:

```
      using System.Text;

namespace DDHTestDelegate
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate string StringDelegate(string inputString, 
                                       string baseString, 
                                       string secondaryBaseString, 
                                       string commonBaseString);

        delegate int IntegerDeleage(int inputInt);

        StringDelegate function1 = (input1, input2, input3, input4) => input1 + "--" + 
                                                                       input2 + "-- " +
                                                                       input3 + "--" +
                                                                       input4;
        StringDelegate function2 = (a, b, c, d) => a + b + c + d;
        StringDelegate function3 = (a, b, c, d) => a + b + " ---- " + c + d;

        static string Test(StringDelegate theFunction, 
                           string inputString1, 
                           string inputString2, 
                           string inputString3, 
                           string inputString4)
        {
            return theFunction(inputString1, inputString2, inputString3, inputString4);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Program v = new Program();
           Console.WriteLine(Test(v.function1, "S1", "S2", "look at this", "How do you do!"));
           Console.WriteLine(Test(v.function2, "S1", "S2", "look at this", "How do you do!"));
           Console.WriteLine(Test(v.function3, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"));
           Console.WriteLine("----");
           Console.WriteLine(Test( (input1, input2, input3, input4) => input1 + 
                                                                      " -- " + 
                                                                      input2 + 
                                                                      " -- " +
                                                                      input3 + 
                                                                      " -- " +
                                                                      input4, 
                                                                      "look at this", 
                                                                      "How do you do!");

           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Figured out my mistake. I was figuring in the values after the => as a parameter up until the first comma, but actually the parameter list does not start until after the first comma.

Working Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DDHTestDelegate
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate string StringDelegate(string inputString, 
                                       string baseString, 
                                       string secondaryBaseString, 
                                       string commonBaseString);

        delegate int IntegerDeleage(int inputInt);

        StringDelegate function1 = (input1, input2, input3, input4) => input1 + "--" + 
                                                                       input2 + "-- " +
                                                                       input3 + "--" +
                                                                       input4;
        StringDelegate function2 = (a, b, c, d) => a + b + c + d;
        StringDelegate function3 = (a, b, c, d) => a + b + " ---- " + c + d;

        static string Test(StringDelegate theFunction, 
                           string inputString1, 
                           string inputString2, 
                           string inputString3, 
                           string inputString4)
        {
            return theFunction(inputString1, inputString2, inputString3, inputString4);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Program v = new Program();

           Console.WriteLine(Test(v.function1, "S1", "S2", "look at this", "How do you do!"));
           Console.WriteLine(Test(v.function2, "S1", "S2", "look at this", "How do you do!"));
           Console.WriteLine(Test(v.function3, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"));

           Console.WriteLine("----");

           Console.WriteLine(Test( (input1, input2, input3, input4) => input1 + " -- " + input2 + " -- " +  input3 + " -- " + "You eat MACs!" + input4, 
                                                                       "Parm1", 
                                                                       "Parm2",
                                                                       "Parm3", 
                                                                       "Parm4"));

           Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the lambda expression. Your `Test` method expects 5 parameters, 1 delegate, and 4 strings, but you've only provided a delegate and 2 strings.

Try providing 2 more, and it will work:

```
Console.WriteLine(Test( (input1, input2, input3, input4) => ..., 
                        "look at this", 
                        "How do you do!", 
                        "another string", 
                        "yet another string")
```

Comment: Maybe I am just not sure how the parameter list works in the delegate lambda expresion. The (...) => parm1, parm2, ... parmN <-- This () parenthesis is the expression after the => is that that parameter list.

Comment: @user3376708 To declare a lambda expression with zero or multiple parameters you need to wrap the parameter list in parentheses (e.g. `(a, b, c, d) => …`). After the end of the lambda expression, the next `,` continues the parameter list of the outer function invocation. If you only had one parameter, the parentheses are not needed around the lambda expression's parameter list, (e.g. `Test(s => …, "foo")`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not specify enough parameters in the call using the lambda expression. Change it to

```
Console.WriteLine(Test( (input1, input2, input3, input4) => input1 + 
                                                              " -- " + 
                                                              input2 + 
                                                              " -- " +
                                                              input3 + 
                                                              " -- " +
                                                              input4, 
                                                              "S1", 
                                                              "S2", 
                                                              "look at this", 
                                                              "How do you do!");
```

I've added `"S1"` and `"S2"` to the parameter list.